# Why crtp works for structs and not for class?

Tags: c++, crtp

Let's consider following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Base{
 };
struct Derived: Base<Derived>{
};
int main() {
    Base<Derived>* base_ptr = new Derived();
}
```

And it works, I mean it compiled. And the same version of that for class:

```
template<typename T>
class Base{
 };
class Derived: Base<Derived>{
};
int main() {
    Base<Derived>* base_ptr = new Derived(); 
//ERROR  ‘Base<Derived>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Derived’
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because for a struct the default access for base classes is `public`, and for a class it's `private`.

Use

```
class Derived: public Base<Derived>{
               ^^^^^^
```

to make it equivalent to the first example.

This has nothing to do with CRTP, you get exactly the same error without CRTP:

```
class Base { };
class Derived : Base { };
Base* base_ptr = new Derived();
```

Comment: @AngelusMortis, I don't understand your comment, sorry. The problem has nothing to do with CRTP, so I don't see why an example using it would help.